# Subspaces: Does closure under scalar multiplication imply additive identity?

Tags: linear-algebra

Working through Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right (second edition)*, I came upon the following assertion:

> If $U$ is a subset of a vector space $V$, then to check if $U$ is a subspace of $V$ we only need to check that $U$ satisfies the following:
>
> **additive identity:**  $ 0 \in U;$
>
> **closed under addition:** $u, v \in U$ implies $u+v \in U;$
>
> **closed under scalar multiplication:** $a \in \mathbb{F}\ $and$\ u \in U$ implies $au \in U.$

My question is: **does closure under scalar multiplication not imply the existence of the additive identity?**

As far as I can reckon, by definition $0 \in \mathbb{F}$, so if $a \in \mathbb{F}\ $and$\ u \in U$ implies $au \in U$, this should in turn imply $0 \in U$. If this is the case, why do we need to check that $U$ contains the additive identity?

Comment: Slade is correct. That is the only case where one does not necessarily imply the other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The case you need to worry about is $U=\emptyset$, in which case closure under scalar multiplication tells you nothing.  As long as $U$ contains at least one element, then you are correct that it is unnecessary to check for $0$.